# Change UserAgent in Code in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

How can I change the `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent` property using reflection?

Thanks

Comment: do you need this at unit test time? in that case you can stub the wole HttpContext.Current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using a ashx (as a proxy) and making a request from that service to the page with a custom useragent header and then printed the answer I got from the other page.

Answer (score 0):

```
string userAgent = "stuff";
PropertyInfo pUserAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetType().GetProperty("UserAgent");
pUserAgent.SetValue(HttpContext.Current.Request, userAgent, null);
```

Sorry, looked up the wrong class. You can't set the property, unless you modify the private field behind it. `HttpRequest.UserAgent` doesn't allow setter access.

Comment: there even is no private field behind it, you can use a tool like Reflector to get some insights in the code behind this property...

Comment: Maybe change the header before Request.UserAgent (and internal logic) uses it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `HttpWebRequest`

[HttpWebRequest.UserAgent Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the incoming request's user agent.  It is the value that is sent by the users browser so I'm not sure why you would want to change it anyways.  If you were creating an outbound request yourself using the HttpWebRequest class you could set its .UserAgent property, or you could add to the .Headers collection if you were using a WebClient class.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current.Request` is read only and so does `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent`. This is so by nature of web, there's no reason why you may want to change anything within HttpRequest object since this has sent by some HttpClient on which you may never have control. Even in a case when you could change it, you're **losing the integrity of the original Request** which is obviously **not recommended**. I don't know what you're trying to achieve by changing the Request object or its properties, but I know for sure that's not the way to go. Try to work out some other way instead of changing the Request object, or write your actual problem statement here and we'll try to help you out.

Comment: For anyone trying to do this (yes, you can have a reason), your options seem to be quite limited. `Request.UserAgent` is read-only. Changing the underlying header, `Request.Headers["User-Agent"]`, (which also loses the original integrity, but *is* allowed) does not change the resulting `Request.UserAgent` value. I'd love to hear a better way than creating a subclass of HttpRequest that allows for setting UserAgent. Doing so requires mirroring all of the data over to the new class instance or creating overloads that refer to the original instance data.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the page Nav_Side.aspx uses some ancient UI components which throw a 500 error unless the browser makes the request in compatibility mode.

I wanted to be able to control compatibility mode on a page-by-page basis, so used Andreas idea of using an ashx to receive the initial request, modify it and transfer to the aspx.

After creating an ashx in Visual Studio, replace the ProcessRequest method with your own code, in my case:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context){
    var headers = context.Request.Headers;
    //set a User-Agent header that mimics compatibility mode for Nav_Side.aspx
    headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0)";       
    context.Server.TransferRequest("Nav_Side.aspx", true, context.Request.HttpMethod, headers);
}
```